# php c++ communication

Tags: php, c++

hi i am new in php,i made the whole code in c++ and want to use this code in php.so i made dll to my code for using it.but i am not able to use this dll in php ,can anybody send me the complete code to use php,c++ extensions.

Comment: I've removed the email from your post, you don't need that here. No one is going to send you an email when we can just answer the question here.

Comment: You can get answers to your questions forwarded to your email by checking the "I'd like email notifications of activity on my questions and answers" on the "prefs" tab of your user page. (Click your name at the top of the screen to get to your user page.)

Comment: And for all we know it's the email address of the bully who kicked your football over to the grumpy neighbour's garden when you two were in third grade and you just wanted to thank him for that with a bazillion spam mails ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole section about some php internals and how to write/build a php extension in the online manual at http://php.net/internals2, and I especially want to point out the [description of the ext_skel script](http://php.net/internals2.buildsys.skeleton) there as it helps you to set up a new "empty" extension project.
And there are alos tools like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) that help you to wrap existing libraries into extensions for numerous languages including PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I made a PHP extension in C++ using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/). The PHP specific documentation can be found [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Php.html).

Since very few online documentation is avaible on using the Zend API I also recommend the book [Extending and Embedding PHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232704X).